# Using values from getters error

Tags: java

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding an Eclipse error. I've got an if statement. I get an error on `val.getVal()`.

> Cannot invoke getVal() on the primitive type double

What does that mean?

```
public Double calculateShare() {

    if (val.getVal() > PublicStock) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what is `val`?

Comment: What don't you understand about the error? Being new doesn't mean you can't research error messages.

Comment: I assume `val` is a `double`. Why are you trying to call `getVal()` on it?

Comment: val is a number. I'm very new to Java, I'm sure you were once new and asked stupid questions. I did my research, still didnt understand, so I asked on here.

Comment: _What_ didn't you understand? That error is very common.

Comment: I'm trying to compare the value returned by my getter with a constant value PublicStock. From what I have learned, that is the way to do it, but I got that error.

Answer (score 1):

Primitive types, like `int`, `long`, `boolean`, `float`, or in your case `double` (note the lowercase first letter), are not objects, and as such, they have no methods. When you do `val.getVal()`, you're trying to invoke a method on a primitive type.

EDIT: the comparison in this case is much simpler:

```
if (val > PublicStock)
```

Remember: primitives are **NOT** objects, they directly hold the value.

Comment: thanks for the help. I'm trying to get the number from val to compare with the constant value I have declared in my if statement. How would I go about doing that?